# Com Port Permissions Python

Tags: python, permissions, serial-port

Working on trying to get serial comminications working between an arduino and my computer. When working off the code that can be seen [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interface-Python-and-Arduino-with-pySerial/?ALLSTEPS) I keep getting this error:

```
raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr,     ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

I have edited the com port used in the aformentioned code to match what I am actually using, but I cant get this error to go away. Here are a few thinks I've tried:

- Ran file as administrator
- Started pycharm as administrator
- Changed the security properties for the directory the program is in
- Unistalled and reinstalled the COM port in device manager
- Restarted Computer

The weird thing is sometimes after I do these fixes it will work once, and then when I stop the program and start it again it once again throws the error.

Comment: Does another program have `COM4` open?

Comment: The only thing that is also using it is the arduino itself. Could the arduino dev software be causing issues?

Comment: Yes, I would suspect the dev SW has the port open.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem before and I realized that I left the serial connection open after serial read program execution completed. Closing the serial connection once done should work.

```
import serial

serial = serial.Serial('COM124', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

#Main function to do something
my_function():
    ...
#end of Main function

my_function()

#adding below line will solve your problem
serial.close()
```